# ruby hidden_field generating wrong tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, hidden-field

I have an issue with a hidden_field tag
i wrote in a view

```
<%= hidden_field('folder_id', value: @folder_to_display.id.to_s) %>
```

and it generates the code below

```
<input id="folder_id_{:value=&gt;1}" name="folder_id[{:value=&gt;1}]" type="hidden" />
```

I've tried different ways but still generates in the same way. Later Im going to access it using jQuery, but the id of generated tag is wrong. PLease help

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`hidden_field_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-hidden_field_tag) instead:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag('folder_id', @folder_to_display.id %>
```